# How do I move the top bar down?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gui, panel

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity Desktop. I would like to move the top bar/panel down. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!